# MVC3 Model Binding and GET Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple html form, and a model corresponding to the form based on the default binder. The HTTPPOST works fine and gets me all the form values into the model on a submit of the form.
However I expected the HTTP GET to display the form with the Username defaulted to Hello. But the view displays a blank form. Could someone kindly explain to me why the default model binder is not able to push the values out to the form on a GET request, but is able to get the values from my form into the model on a POST request. Thanks.

-----CONTROLLER -----

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SimpleFormModel application)
    {
        return View(application);
    }
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index ()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        SimpleFormModel simplefm = new SimpleFormModel();
        simplefm.UserName = "Hello";
        return View(simplefm);
    }
```

---MODEL ---

```
public class SimpleFormModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Dob { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

--------VIEW--------------------------

```
@model MVC3MobileApplication.Models.SimpleFormModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<p>
    To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
</p>


<form action="">
<fieldset>
<legend>Personal information:</legend>
Name: <input type="text" size="30" name="SimpleFormModel.UserName" /><br />
E-mail: <input type="text" size="30" name ="SimpleFormModel.Email"/><br />
Date of birth: <input type="text" size="10" name ="SimpleFormModel.Dob"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use HTML helpers to generate your input fields instead of hardcoding them as you did:

```
@model MVC3MobileApplication.Models.SimpleFormModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal information:</legend>
        Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName, new { size = "30" })
        <br />
        E-mail: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { size = "30" })
        <br />
        Date of birth: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Dob, new { size = "10" })
    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

The HTML helpers will use the model values to generate the corresponding input fields and populate them.

Comment: I thought if the default binder is programmed to get them out of the request and bind to the model on a post even wthout the html helpers, it would work the otherway too, without having to use the htmlhelpers. I was hoping to keep the view as pure html as possible.

Comment: @RekhaJayaram, the model binder is used to parse posted values. If you want to output a value in an input field in HTML you will have to use the value attribute: `<input type="text" size="30" name="SimpleFormModel.UserName" value="some value" />` which is exactly what the helpers do.

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time to explain that. That really helped me understand what is going on.

Comment: @RekhaJayaram, if this answer was helpful for you make sure to [mark it as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your HTML Textbox with this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.UserName)
```

Otherwise .net is unable to fill the value of the field...